# Looping through each id retrieve value of objects in 1 dimentional array and 2 dimentional array

Tags: jquery

Looping through each id retrieve value of objects in 1 dimentional array and 2 dimentional array

New to jQuery.. :(

Comment: Read it twice, but it just unclear(at least to me).

Comment: you cant have same ID, it should be unique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use class instead of ID, id is unique per page... regarding your needs:
Actually you need somehting like that:

```
var data = []
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.both').each(function(){
        ta = $(this).children('textarea').val();
        cb = $(this).children('input:checked').val()
        data.push({t:ta,c:cb})
    });
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        $('body').append('<p>t:'+value.t+' c: '+value.c+'</p>');
    })
})
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/xu8xj/)

Answer (score 2):

At first: you should change id  for class and then

$(both)

for:

```
$(".both")
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, I have that properly written in my code in my program.

Comment: I need 15 reputation for that.. :(

Comment: You need 15 reputation to upvote but you can mark my answer as accepted (click image at left of `$(".both")` ) ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, build the HTML like this :

```
<form id="myform" action="myscript.php" method="get">
    <div>
        <div><textarea name="mytextarea[]"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes1[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes2[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes3[]"><div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><textarea name="mytextarea[]"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes1[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes2[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes3[]"><div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><textarea name="mytextarea[]"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes1[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes2[]"><div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes3[]"><div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As with all forms, when it is submitted, the query string will be composed automatically, comprising `name=value` pairs of field names and user-entered data.

Alternatively, you can build your own query string in javascript and the simplest way by far is to use jQuery's `.serialize()` :

```
var data = $("#myform").serialize();
```

Typically, this would be done in order to submit the form via AJAX, eg.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    data: $("myform").serialize(),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ...
    }.
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    }
});
```

With either type of submission, the `[]` notation makes each field name available in PHP (and other server-side languages) as 1-dimension arrays of values. For example, the first block of values are given by the expressions.

```
$_GET['mytextarea'][0];
$_GET['mycheckboxes1'][0];
$_GET['mycheckboxes2'][0];
$_GET['mycheckboxes3'][0];
```

Actions involving the data would typically be performed in a loop.